# better building of kd-trees

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, kdtree

Has anyone ever tried improving kd-trees using the following method?

1. Dividing each numeric dimension via   some 1-d clustering method (e.g. Jenks Natural Breaks Optimization, or FayyadIranni or xyz...)
2. Sorting the dimensions on the expected value of the variance reduction within each division of that dimension
3. Building the KD-tree top-down selecting attributes from the order found in (2)
4. Breaking dimensions at each level of the KD-tree using the divisions found in (1)

And just to say the obvious. If (3) terminates when #rows is (say) less than 30 then nearest neighbor would require 30 distance measures, not N.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, I'm just describing C4.5 with a stop criteria of sqrt(N).  My "new idea" many not be an innovation after all.

Answer (score 0):

You want the tree to be balanced, so there is not much leeway in terms of where to split.
Also, you want the construction to be *fast*.

If you put in an O(n^2) method during construction, construction will likely be the new bottleneck.

In many cases, the very simple (original) k-d-tree is just as fast as any of the "optimized" techniques that try to determine the "best" splitting axis.